# How do I load a local model with torch.hub.load?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I need to avoid downloading the model from the web (due to restrictions on the machine installed).

This works, but it downloads the model from the Internet

```
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.9.0', 'deeplabv3_resnet101', pretrained=True)
```

I have placed the `.pth` file and the `hubconf.py` file in the /tmp/ folder and changed my code to

```
model = torch.hub.load('/tmp/', 'deeplabv3_resnet101', pretrained=True, source='local')
```

but to my surprise, it still downloads the model from the Internet. What am I doing wrong? How can I load the model locally?

Just to give you a bit more details, I'm doing all this in a Docker container that has a read-only volume at runtime, so that's why the download of new files fails.

Comment: It seems the option to load locally was not present in some earlier versions of PyTorch. Which version are you using?

Comment: Collecting torch==1.8.1
  Downloading torch-1.8.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (804.1 MB)
Collecting torchsummary==1.5.1
  Downloading torchsummary-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.8 kB)
Collecting torchvision==0.9.1
  Downloading torchvision-0.9.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (17.4 MB)

Comment: The code near `pretrained=True,s ource` does not seem to be syntactically correct. Is it in the original?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take to get a shippable model on a machine without an Internet connection.

1. Load DeepLab with a pretrained model on a normal machine, use a [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) compiler to export it as a graph, and put it into the machine. The Script is easy to follow:

   ```
    # To export
    model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.9.0', 'deeplabv3_resnet101', pretrained=True).eval()
    traced_graph = torch.jit.trace(model, torch.randn(1, 3, H, W))
    traced_graph.save('DeepLab.pth')

    # To load
    model = torch.jit.load('DeepLab.pth').eval().to(device)
   ```

   In this case, the weights and network structure is saved as computational graph, so you won't need any extra files.
2. Take a look at [torchvision's GitHub repository](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/segmentation/segmentation.py#L18).

   There's a [download URL](https://download.pytorch.org/models/deeplabv3_resnet101_coco-586e9e4e.pth) for DeepLabV3 with Resnet101 backbone weights.

   You can download those weights once, and then use deeplab from torchvision with ***pretrained=False*** flag and load weights manually.

   ```
    model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.9.0', 'deeplabv3_resnet101', pretrained=False)
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load('downloaded weights path'))
   ```

   Take in consideration, there might be a ***['state_dict']*** or some similar parent key in state dict, where you would use:

   ```
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load('downloaded weights path')['state_dict'])
   ```

Comment: what are H and W?

Comment: I assume it's the minimum 224 specified by the deeplab specs. When I try this the trace the error:     `module._c._create_method_from_trace(
RuntimeError: Encountering a dict at the output of the tracer might cause the trace to be incorrect, this is only valid if the container structure does not change based on the module's inputs. Consider using a constant container instead (e.g. for `list`, use a `tuple` instead. for `dict`, use a `NamedTuple` instead). If you absolutely need this and know the side effects, pass strict=False to trace() to allow this behavior.`

Comment: tried it with strict=False, seems to work so far. I'll spin up the docker environment and see if that works

Comment: H and W are Height and Width of the image (tensor) and you're right - minimum size required by DeepLabV3 is 224x224. load_state_dict(chkpt, strict=False) is right way to load only required weights. Final advice would be - test the model outputs by visualization, don't deploy it right away.

Comment: The jit failed because of DeepLab's output format: OrderedDict -> ['out', 'aux']. 
But, by passing strict=False to JIT tracer, it'll compile as a graph that outputs only ['out'] with size of [1, 21, H, W].

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked so I marked this as the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

```
model_name='best.pt'
model = torch.hub.load(os.getcwd(), 'custom', source='local', path = model_name, force_reload = True)
```

This worked for me. Default source is github.

Answer (score 0):

This woks for me:

```
    # model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.6.0', 'deeplabv3_resnet101', pretrained=True)
    model_path = '~/.cache/torch/hub/checkpoints/deeplabv3_resnet101_coco-586e9e4e.pth'
    model = deeplabv3_resnet101(pretrained=True)
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
    model.eval()
```